# How to lock liquidity tokens on Pancakeswap or Uniswap

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

[image]

Tell me how to Lock liquidity on Pancakeswap or Uniswap ?

Comment: Send the LP tokens to an address you're not in control of. (and no one else is, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block liquidity + this you will increase confidence in front of investors, I block now at openlock.io/ref/31, no problems.

[image]